# How to set Firefox Binary path of firefox in selenium in Linux?

Tags: linux, selenium, firefox

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Cannot find firefox binary in PATH. Make sure firefox is installed. OS appears to be: LINUX Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:43:45 -0700'
System info: host: 'skalia', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.19.0-25-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.Executable.<init>(Executable.java:75)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary.<init>(FirefoxBinary.java:60)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary.<init>(FirefoxBinary.java:56)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:127)
at pack.SeleTest.main(SeleTest.java:10)
```

This is the error i get during running selenium script which is working Fine on Window PC. I set all the Build path. Add all selenium jars. 
Help me to solve it.

Answer (score 3):

IN JAVA Language:

If you install firefox in default location you just write:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

For other location you can coding like below:

```
File browserAppPath = null;
if (Platform.getCurrent().is(Platform.WINDOWS)) {
    browserAppPath = new File("C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla   Firefox\\firefox.exe");
    if (!browserAppPath.exists()) {
       browserAppPath = new File("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
   }
} else {
   // Ubuntu
   browserAppPath = new File("/usr/bin/firefox/firefox-bin");
}
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver( new FirefoxBinary(browserAppPath), new FirefoxProfile());
```

Comment: Thanks for save my day :)

Answer (score 2):

**Either** add your Firefox binary to the PATH variable **or** set it programmatically using a constructor of `FirefoxDriver` taking a `FirefoxBinary`, like this one:

```
FirefoxDriver(FirefoxBinary binary, FirefoxProfile profile);
```

To find out the path to your firefox binary on Linux, run this command in a shell:

```
which firefox
```

If this does not show a path or shows an error nessage, then Firefox is not installed on your Linux system (if it is installed on your Windows PC, then this is the reason why it works there).