# Selenium: Unable to locate requested binary

Tags: selenium, firefox

**Setup**

- **OS**: Ubuntu 17
- **Selenium**: 2.53.1

  - Launching with param: `-Dwebdriver.firefox.bin="/home/tyler/Documents/Code/dev/tests/functional/firefox-47.0.1/firefox-bin"`
- **Firefox**: 47.0.1

  - Install Path: `/home/tyler/Documents/Code/dev/tests/functional/firefox-47.0.1/`
- **Driver**: geckodriver 0.11.1

***Note:*** I've tried using the most recent version of selenium, geckodriver, and Firefox as well as Chrome but there appears to be a compatibility issue because Selenium crashes when PHPUnit launches the browsers. [[Details Here]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44331490/selenium-crashing-securityerror-the-operation-is-insecure)

## Issue

When initiating my tests Selenium returns the text shown below. The most relevant part appears to be `WARN - Exception: 'webdriver.firefox.bin' property set, but unable to locate the requested binary: "/home/tyler/Documents/Code/dev/tests/functional/firefox-47.0.1/firefox-bin"`

Digging into Selenium's repo, I see [here](https://github.com/akiellor/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/internal/Executable.java#L131) that this is an error thrown when a Java method File.Exist() does not return true. In an attempt to resolve this I executed chmod 777 on the Selenium standalone server jar as well as the Firefox directory to ensure that it could be read from.

```
13:53:30.688 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{0={platform=[{value=LINUX}]}, browserName=firefox}]])
13:53:30.694 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{0={platform=[{value=LINUX}]}, browserName=firefox}]
13:53:30.698 WARN - Exception thrown
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
System info: host: 'tyler-Precision-5520', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.10.0-21-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.execute(DefaultSession.java:183)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.<init>(DefaultSession.java:119)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.createSession(DefaultSession.java:95)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverSessions.newSession(DefaultDriverSessions.java:124)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.NewSession.handle(NewSession.java:59)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.NewSession.handle(NewSession.java:1)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.rest.ResultConfig.handle(ResultConfig.java:111)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.JsonHttpCommandHandler.handleRequest(JsonHttpCommandHandler.java:79)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.handleRequest(DriverServlet.java:204)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.doPost(DriverServlet.java:166)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.service(DriverServlet.java:132)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:428)
        at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.dispatch(ServletHandler.java:680)
        at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:571)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1526)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1479)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpServer.service(HttpServer.java:920)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.service(HttpConnection.java:820)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handleNext(HttpConnection.java:986)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:837)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.SocketListener.handleConnection(SocketListener.java:243)
        at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadedServer.handle(ThreadedServer.java:358)
        at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadPool$PoolThread.run(ThreadPool.java:537)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
System info: host: 'tyler-Precision-5520', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.10.0-21-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.FirefoxDriverProvider.callConstructor(FirefoxDriverProvider.java:101)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.FirefoxDriverProvider.newInstance(FirefoxDriverProvider.java:68)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory.newInstance(DefaultDriverFactory.java:60)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:222)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:176)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.FirefoxDriverProvider.callConstructor(FirefoxDriverProvider.java:91)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary.<init>(FirefoxBinary.java:60)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary.<init>(FirefoxBinary.java:56)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.getBinary(FirefoxDriver.java:203)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:128)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 'webdriver.firefox.bin' property set, but unable to locate the requested binary: "/home/tyler/Documents/Code/dev/tests/functional/firefox-47.0.1/firefox-bin"
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
System info: host: 'tyler-Precision-5520', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.10.0-21-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.Executable.locateFirefoxBinaryFromSystemProperty(Executable.java:145)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.Executable.<clinit>(Executable.java:45)
        ... 18 more
13:53:30.701 WARN - Exception: 'webdriver.firefox.bin' property set, but unable to locate the requested binary: "/home/tyler/Documents/Code/dev/tests/functional/firefox-47.0.1/firefox-bin"
```

Comment: Just a wild guess, but shouldn't your reference of "/home/tyler/..." be "/users/tyler/..." ?

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to install Firefox in the default directory so you can do:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

You could also add your directory to your System's [PATH](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) variable (requires a restart).

Lastly you can define the path in code. Java Example from another [Q/A on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42111269/6933359):

```
File browserAppPath = new File("/usr/bin/firefox/firefox-bin");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver( new FirefoxBinary(browserAppPath), new FirefoxProfile());
```