# Cannot find Firefox binary path in ubntu(linux)

Tags: java, selenium

I am using Linux(Ubuntu) when run the web application it gives error:

> Firefox cannot find binary path

I am using Firefox 46.0 and selenium 2.53.0.

Comment: Please have a look at this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094021/how-to-set-firefox-binary-path-of-firefox-in-selenium-in-linux

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work in your case.

```
WebDriver firefox = new FirefoxDriver();
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
firefox = new FirefoxDriver(new FirefoxBinary(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"),
"/tools/FirefoxPortable/FirefoxPortable.exe")), profile);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by using simple command in console, it should return path:

```
which firefox
```

And here is list of FF [download site](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/) for binaries.

Usually path is like this:

> "/usr/bin/firefox/firefox-bin"

Hope this helps,